# Hit Highlighting with SQl Server 2008 FTS

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, highlighting

This question was here [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089/how-to-do-hit-highlighting-of-results-from-a-sql-server-full-text-query) but there was no answer, so trying one more time - how to do hit highlighting of results with SQL 2008 FTS?

So far I found [SQLHighlighter](http://www.sqlhighlighter.com/) but it is commercial product. I also tried solution described in this book http://apress.com/book/view/9781430215943 but performance was extremely poor. As last resort I tried Lucene.Net Highlighter, but it is linked with Lucene (which I'm trying to get away from).

Can someone recommend other way?

Comment: I've just released [ThinkHighlight](http://www.interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkhighlight/) so you can try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is a listed 'bug' of FTS that it does not return any hit tracking information

You are left with parsing the query yourself, and matching that to each result rows text columns and doing the highlight

This could be quite simple or very hard depending on how you are building the FTS queries