# Retrieving text from FileTable SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, filetable

Is it possible to retrieve the actual text from a File Table in SQL Server 2014?

I want to implement some hit-highlighting functionality, but in order to do so, I need to retrieve the actual text in the file I indexed, since the content is in a varbinary column.

If it's not possible, I suppose the only alternative to do this is forgetting about FileTables and implementing an application-side "document reader", so that I'll have real text inside my "file_stream" column instead of the varbinary. Or maybe even defining an UDF that uses iFilters behind some C# code, right?

Please, any advice would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do start with your own implementation, take a look at the very similar question:
[SQL Server 2012 FTS with Hit-Highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437330/will-sql-server-2012-fts-have-native-support-for-hit-highlighting)

Also this blog entry from 2012 is still current:
[Hit-Highlighting in Full-Text Search](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/hit-highlighting-in-full-text-search)

I would take a look at the mentioned `HitHighlight` function (which is actually a commercial product, [ThinkHighlight](http://www.interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkhighlight/)). Most likely it's not worth the effort to build your own solution. But if you do so - tell me ;)