# Show matching keywords per each document returned from a SQL Server full-text query

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, hit-highlighting

Given an arbitrary full text search (FTS) query, it's required to list keywords from the resulting document which match the query. For example, `test or rest` produces list of 3 documents where 1st one contains only `test`, 2nd one contains both of the words and the 3rd one has only `rest`. The explanation should produce 3 lists: (`test`) (`test`, `rest`) (`rest`) for the end user to understand why the documents appeared in the query output.

The question is related to hit-highlighting and I've explored existing solutions (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623815/Hit-Highlight-for-SQL-Server-Full-Text-Search or [How to do hit-highlighting of results from a SQL Server full-text query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089/how-to-do-hit-highlighting-of-results-from-a-sql-server-full-text-query)). Those solutions rely on `sys.dm_fts_parser` fed with hard-coded `FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL` to produce all permutations of the search term.

Particularly, solutions relying on `sys.dm_fts_parser` seem to stumble upon a prefix search. For example, given 2 queries `test` and `"test*"` `select content from table where contains(content, @query, language 1033)` produces different result sets, but `select * from sys.dm_fts_parser(@query, 1033, 0, 1)` yields 2 absolutely identical recordsets, which doesn't give any clue as to why query outputs are different.

Anyone has any experience with similar cases?

Comment: Have you tried [ThinkHighlight](http://www.interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkhighlight/)?

Comment: I know about the library, though I haven't actually tried it. In my case it was ruled out because it requires to upload an unsafe assembly into SQL server, which is not allowed in my production environment.

Comment: Sometimes you can't recreate internal SQL Server functionality without "getting in". By the way, "unsafe" absolutely doesn't mean the assembly is unsafe for use, it's only a code permission.